# Import JWK signature from file and verify information Web Cryptography API

Tags: javascript, cryptography, sign, verify, jwk

Fail to verify signature using Web Cryptography API and RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5 algorithm keys.

1. Save the signature generated with the [sign function](https://github.com/diafygi/webcrypto-examples#rsassa-pkcs1-v1_5---sign) in postgreSQL as a string:

```
        window.crypto.subtle
          .sign("RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5", key, this.str2ab(hash))
          .then(sigNature => {
            const sig = this.ab2hex(sigNature); //save sig -> postgreSQL
          });
```

2. I try to verify using signature that I get fron postgreSQL:

```
window.crypto.subtle
          .verify(
            "RSASSA-PKCS1-v1_5",
            key,
            this.str2ab(_signature), //from pSQL
            this.str2ab(_hash) //from pSQL
          )
          .then(isVerified => {
            console.log(isVerified);
          });
```

Utils:
* String -> ArrayBuffer function:

```
private str2ab(str) {
    var buf = new ArrayBuffer(str.length * 2); // 2 bytes for each char
    var bufView = new Uint16Array(buf);
    for (var i = 0, strLen = str.length; i < strLen; i++) {
      bufView[i] = str.charCodeAt(i);
    }
    return buf;
  }
```

- ArrayBuffer -> HEX function:

```
private ab2hex(buffer) {
    // buffer is an ArrayBuffer
    return Array.prototype.map
      .call(new Uint8Array(buffer), x => ("00" + x.toString(16)).slice(-2))
      .join("");
  }
```

The problem is that I always get "false" as response from verify function even if I used correct key pair to sign and verify